# ParcelJs optimizer & class names

Tags: css, classname, parcel

I'm starting using parcelJs, and it's a killer.

In dev mode, I get no problem but in production nothing is working:

My framework is generating css classes names dynamically from typescript classes name.

For example if my typescript class is named "Header", the generated dom element will have a class name "x-header" and I use this in my css.
Now, with optimization on, my class name for "Header" is something like "$35465543567436"

Do you know if there is a way to keep optimisations & classes names ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, parcel is using terser for minification.

Just add a file named *.terserrc* with this content:

```
{
    "keep_classnames": true
}
```